# How can you subtract dates with different time formats in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time, format

I'm working with an API that returns dates in the following format:

```
2020-06-08 22:51:11 -0300
```

and I need to calculate how much time has elapsed until certain event happens for which I'm using Date.now() which outputs milliseconds since 1970.

```
1591667758424
```

So I got two time formats what I can't subtract. What is the best solution to work with both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string date to the same format using [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), doing like that:

```
const date = new Date('2020-06-08 22:51:11 -0300').getTime()
console.log(date - 1591667758424 )
```

Comment: i think this will give you the time zone difference it doesn't take it into account

Comment: An observation, if the timestamp that returns `const date = new Date('2020-06-08 22:51:11 -0300').getTime()` you convert it back to date it gives a different than the original date `new Date(timestamp)` and I think the calculation would not be correct

Comment: That's true. In my case, I'm at the same timezone that the date in the example, so I had no problem. Depending on the situation, he ca just removes the tz info from the string. So both dates will be at the tz of the operation system.

Comment: @Mario do you mind having a look at my code below ,and tell me what you think thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the calcuation should be performed like this

```
srvtmili= new Date('2020-06-08 22:51:11').getTime()
h=60*60*1000
timedifference=4*h //3 hours from UTC and 1 hour (dls) from GMT 
srvrtimeconvtolocal=timedifference+srvtmili //convert to local GMT in this case
localtimeinmil=1591667758424
timedifference=1591667758424-srvrtimeconvtolocal
console.log('difference is',timedifference/(1000),'in seconds')
```

Comment: Thank you for requesting my opinion, but I do not have the authority to properly interpret your solution, working with dates in different time zones is a pending task for me.